# Input radio add name in the class

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, radio-button, attr

```
<div typ="elementRadio" class="element elementRadio">
<input type="radio">
<input type="radio">
<input type="radio">
</div>

<div typ="elementRadio" class="element elementRadio">
<input type="radio">
<input type="radio">
<input type="radio">
</div>

.................
<div typ="elementRadio" class="element elementRadio">
<input type="radio">
<input type="radio">
<input type="radio">
</div>
```

They need to add a random name Input. So that the radio input had a different name in each class.

My code

```
   $('.elementRadio input:radio').each(function () {
       $( "input:radio" ).attr( "name", "name1" );
       alert($( "input:radio" ).attr( "name"));
    });
```

All name

Comment: How are you generating the radio buttons? Can you not put a name in the source at that point?

Comment: I will never know the exact number Input. Everything will be randomly

Comment: That's not what I meant. I'm asking how do you create the HTML for these radio buttons? It would be much, much easier to add the `name` property to them at that point. You also don't seem to be giving any radio a `value`, so their purpose is a little redundant

Comment: @MartinCaruk If I understand right, what you are looking for is a way to loop over wrapper (`.elementRadio`) and add name to `input`. Am I right?

Comment: @Rajesh  i need 
<div typ="elementRadio" class="element elementRadio">
<input type="radio" name="name1">
<input type="radio" name="name1">
<input type="radio" name="name1">
</div>

<div typ="elementRadio" class="element elementRadio">
<input type="radio" name="name2">
<input type="radio" name="name2">
<input type="radio" name="name2">
</div>
Atd ......

Answer (score 3):

You should loop over `.elementRadio` and then add names to `input:radio`.

You can use `index` to compute unique names.

```js
$('.elementRadio').each(function(i) {
  $(this).find('input:radio').attr("name", "name"+ (i+1));
  console.log($(this).find('input:radio').attr("name"));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div typ="elementRadio" class="element elementRadio">
  <input type="radio">
  <input type="radio">
  <input type="radio">
</div>

<div typ="elementRadio" class="element elementRadio">
  <input type="radio">
  <input type="radio">
  <input type="radio">
</div>

.................
<div typ="elementRadio" class="element elementRadio">
  <input type="radio">
  <input type="radio">
  <input type="radio">
</div>
```

Comment: Good job THIS IS PERFECT :)

Comment: You should also suggest to to remove the `typ="elementRadio"` from the `div.element.elementRadio`

Comment: It is out of the scope of this question though, you are correct. I'll leave it to OP(@MartinCaruk) to rectify it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate over all the `.element.elementRadio` elements and use the `index` of [jQuery.each()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/)

Also check that you have to correct `typ="elementRadio"` within the divs

Code:

```js
$('.element.elementRadio').each(function (index) {
  $(this).find('input:radio').attr('name', 'name_' + index);

  // Console log: names
  console.log($(this).find('input:radio').attr('name'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="element elementRadio">
  <input type="radio">
  <input type="radio">
  <input type="radio">
</div>

<div class="element elementRadio">
  <input type="radio">
  <input type="radio">
  <input type="radio">
</div>

<div class="element elementRadio">
  <input type="radio">
  <input type="radio">
  <input type="radio">
</div>
```

Comment: The name should be the same for each group of three radios, otherwise every single one can be selected.

Comment: I hope you got the answer to your comment

Comment: Our answers are same now, but when I answered, they were different and your edits made them similar. Also I do not understand the reason for the question, but still wanted to clarify it.

Answer (score 1):

Check this out. 
I have made an first iteration for each radio group and then set every radio input lie in the group same name. I also made name in array format so you can get the data in array.
Hope this will work for you

```js
$('.elementRadio').each(function (i) {
        var name = "name["+(i+1)+"]";
        $(this).find("input:radio").attr( "name", name );
            console.log(name );
        
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div typ="elementRadio" class="element elementRadio">
    <input type="radio">
    <input type="radio">
    <input type="radio">
</div>

<div typ="elementRadio" class="element elementRadio">
    <input type="radio">
    <input type="radio">
    <input type="radio">
</div>

.................
<div typ="elementRadio" class="element elementRadio">
    <input type="radio">
    <input type="radio">
    <input type="radio">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this random `name` of each radio input

```js
var count =1;
   $('.elementRadio input:radio').each(function (a) {
       if(a== 3)
         {   count=2; }
     else if(a == 6){count=3}
     $(this).attr( "name", "name"+count );
      console.log($(this).attr( "name"));
   
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div typ="elementRadio" class="element elementRadio">
<input type="radio">
<input type="radio">
<input type="radio">
</div>

<div typ="elementRadio" class="element elementRadio">
<input type="radio">
<input type="radio">
<input type="radio">
</div>

.................
<div typ="elementRadio" class="element elementRadio">
<input type="radio">
<input type="radio">
<input type="radio">
</div>
```

Comment: The name should be the same for each group of three radios, otherwise every single one can be selected.

Comment: That's works, although it's hideous. See @Rajesh's answer for a much better implementation